# quick help needed base class undefined

Tags: c++, class, include, public

Couldn't find a solution to this anywhere

here is my file layout

SDK.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Object.h"
#include "Panel.h"
```

Object.H

```
#pragma once
#include "SDK.h"

class BaseObject
{
etc...
}
```

Panel.h

```
#pragma once
#include "SDK.h"

class Panel : public BaseObject
{
etc...
}
```

and then the error

```
Panel.h(5): error C2504: 'BaseObject' : base class undefined
```

can somebody please tell me how to do it correctly? it's probably a very simple fix :(

EDIT: I looked and couldn't solve it, would I have to create a new file and include them in .CPP files?

Comment: Do you have semicolons after class definitions in your code? Also, you're running into circular include dependency with SDK.h and Object.h.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular C++ Header Includes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281641/circular-c-header-includes)

Comment: yes i do, and still cant solve it

Comment: @LogicStuff `#pragma once` prevents multiple / circular inclusion

Comment: yup, did that too on all header files

Comment: @MikeMB [Another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918250/pragma-once-and-include-issues) - `#pragma once` does not prevent circular inclusion

Comment: @jacobharris: Pleas provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeMB uhh just do the things i said and include SDK.h in main

Comment: @LogicStuff:`pragma one` DOES prevent circular **inclusion**. The problem in the linked question is circular **dependency**, which you have to resolve by forward declaration.

Comment: @MikeMB OK, I used wrong terms. But the dupplicate I proposed is nonetheless right.

Comment: @LogicStuff: What I wanted to say is that it is a different problem - irrespective of what you call it. There is no circular dependency in the code jacob shows - only a very bad include strategy that - depending on the way he included the files in the source files - will blow up or not. Thats why I asked for an actual mcve..

Comment: @jacobharris: Aside from the fact, that I agree with Dietmar's guess, I'm to lazy to create a bunch of files, copy your code and correct your spelling mistakes just to see that it can't reproduce your problem because your question lacks the necessary details. If you want help, you should be willing to invest at least a minimal amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include any information about the translation unit failing to compile the code. Thus, I'm speculating. My guess is that you have something including `Object.h` first:

- the compiler starts including `Object.h` and marks it to not include again
- the compiler includes `SDK.h`, suspending inclusion of `Object.h` and marks it to not include again
- inclusion of `Object.h` is skipped
- the compiler includes `Panel.h`, suspending inclusion of `SDK.h` and marks it to not include again
- inclusion of `SDK.h` is skipped
- the definition of `Panel` is reached but `BaseObject` is not defined, yet, and you get the error

The fix is not to include `SDK.h` from either `Object.h` or `Panel.h`. Instead `Panel.h` should include `Object.h` and both headers should include whatever else they need.

Comment: i see, but if i wanted to add like Button.h what would i do then?

Comment: @jacobharris: you'd include the header(s) defining its direct base class(es) as well as headers for everything it needs declarations for. If you want to provide a convenience header for users of the library you'd include the newly created header there, too.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `#include "SDK.H"` from Object.h
- [Last resort]If problem still doesn't solves , use `header guards` , here is the [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020211/1953449) for it.

Comment: Did you actually check this? If so, can you explain, why this helps?

Comment: simple base class is declaring more than one time , so remove it . i know pragma is there , but in this particular case it don't work.

Comment: While I guess that your suggestion will probably work, I'm pretty sure, the explanation is wrong, because a) that would produce a different compiler error and b) mean that the compiler would not handle `pragma once` correctly, which - i think - is very unlikely.